# How to set a text to a Preference

Tags: android, preference

How can I set text (version name, I know the code for that) to a Preference in PreferenceActivity?

```
String versionName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
```

Comment: You cant modify the manifest via code. If you want to change the version name, manually change the manifest's version name attribute.

Comment: No, I wanted to set the text to a preference, not change the version name!

Comment: Sorry i miss understood, but you are being unclear. The text of what? To what preference?  unless you mean text *of* a preference

Comment: You might use the **deprecated** method `findPreference()` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)) to get a reference to your desired preference in the PreferenceScreen.

Comment: This is such a broad question it would be best I think for you to try it out.  [This](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/) is a decent tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as Funkystein suggests to set the preference from the `PreferenceActivity` using `findPreference()`. Which is probably the best route. Or depending on where you are, call from any actvity

```
  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("<PREFERENCE NAME>", versionName).commit();
```

Where `"<PREFERENCE NAME>"` is the string name of the preference you are trying to change.
THen when you load the preferenceactivity, it will be set.